# jQuery UI accordion that keeps some element stays open after collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I would like to put more function in jquery accordion by providing user some information that still visible inside an accordion section if user click a button.
This would be more like this:
From this:
[image: accordion partial collapse]

and the blue element still not collapsed even after we collapsed the First header like this:

[image]

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "> div.wrap >h3", collapsible: true, active: false });
    $("input[name='btn']").click(function() {
            $("#newdiv").html("<div>This element stays visible after the header collapsed</div>");
        });         
    })

})(jQuery);
```

Have a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gHrv/248/) I created.

Of course the element that still visible is inside the content, not in header. but it would still visible even after the content is collapsed. is it possible with jquery?

Comment: So whats the question ?

Comment: What should happen when the panel is collapsed? What should happen when the button is clicked? Please clarify your question above.

Comment: Protip: you seem to have doubled up on your document.ready wrappers. The outer function probably isn't necessary. Just use `jQuery(function($) {...});`

Comment: @isherwood : sorry, I improved my question. hope it clear enough.